# C# nested properties

Tags: c#, class

I have a model like this that includes the OwnerProductRegistration and AttachmentList.

```
public class OwnerProductRegistration
{
    public string CustomerFirstName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerPhoneMobile { get; set; }
    public List<AttachmentList> AttachmentLists { get; set; }
}

public class AttachmentList
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

OwnerProductRegistration model = new OwnerProductRegistration();
AttachmentList attachmentList = new AttachmentList();

model.CustomerFirstName = "Test";
model.CustomerPhoneMobile = "1234567890";

attachmentList.FileName = "FileNameTest";
attachmentList.Description = "foo";
```

I want to send the entire 'OwnerProductRegistration' model with the AttachmentList data included. When I check the value contents of model, it shows the AttachmentList as null. How do I include the AttachmentList data with the model?

Answer (score 4):

You must first instantiate the list on your model property, then add the attachment list to it. You can accomplish both like so:

```
model.CustomerFirstName = "Test";
model.CustomerPhoneMobile = "1234567890";

attachmentList.FileName = "FileNameTest";
attachmentList.Description = "foo";

model.AttachmentLists = new List<AttachmentList> { attachmentList };
```

If you don't want to use a collection initializer, you can break the operation up like this:

```
model.AttachmentLists = new List<AttachmentList>();
model.AttachmentLists.Add(attachmentList);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not setting the `AttachmentLists` property anywhere. Try this, it's similar to yours, but the property is set in the last line.

```
public class OwnerProductRegistration
{
  public string CustomerFirstName { get; set; }
  public string CustomerPhoneMobile { get; set; }
  public List<AttachmentList> AttachmentLists { get; set; }
}

public class AttachmentList
{
  public string FileName { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
}

OwnerProductRegistration model = new OwnerProductRegistration();
AttachmentList attachmentList = new AttachmentList();

model.CustomerFirstName = "Test";
model.CustomerPhoneMobile = "1234567890";

attachmentList.FileName = "FileNameTest";
attachmentList.Description = "foo";

model.AttachmentLists = new List<AttachmentList> { attachmentList };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can as well use *Object Initializer* and *Collection initializer* syntax available from C#3 like below

```
OwnerProductRegistration model = new OwnerProductRegistration
{
  CustomerFirstName = "Test",
  CustomerPhoneMobile = "1234567890",
  AttachmentLists = new List<AttachmentList>
  {
    new AttachmentList
    {
      FileName = "FileNameTest",
      Description = "foo",
    }
  }
}
```